# Bull Arena for bullmq - TypeError: as of 3.0.0, bull-arena requires that the queue constructors be provided to Arena

Tags: redis, bull, bullmq

I'm using bullmq not bull library

```
import BullMQ from 'bullmq';
import Arena from 'bull-arena';

const arenaConfig = Arena({
  BullMQ,
  queues: bullQueues,
});
```

got an error `TypeError: as of 3.0.0, bull-arena requires that the queue constructors be provided to Arena`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error today. but bull and bull-arena.
I solved by using
`import * as Bull from 'bull';` instead of `import Bull from 'bull'`
also, after that, I had another error. which solved with
`const Arena = require('bull-arena');`  rather than `import Arena from 'bull-arena';`